# Phase space portrait for dynamical system with Bifurcations

Tags: computational-physics, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems, bifurcation

I have this dynamical system
$$x'=y, y'=-x^3-y+mx$$
and I want to draw the phace space diagram for $m=-1/8, m=1/4,$ the bifurcation points. 1st of all I cant find what kind of bifruction I have( I go from stable focus to stable node and sadle), does it have a name(?). I compute the equilibrium points and theirs stability and  i get these phase portraits for $m=-1/8$:

[image: phase portraits for m=1/4]

and for $m=1/4$,

[image: phase portraits for m=1/4]

which seem wrong. The grey lines are the trajectories, I  computed by numerical integration and plotted the corresponding invariant manifolds (blue and red lines).

Lastly I can drop the Mathematica code I used and let you see if I have any mistakes.

https://we.tl/t-8c4XKGoIKY

Answer (score 1):

Could you be plotting the same phase portrait twice instead, the one for $m=1/4$, instead of plotting two different ones for $m=1/4$ and $m=-1/8$?

I used the following little python script I wrote to help me draw phase portraits of planar vector fields:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def solve_IVP(vector_field, x_in, y_in, t_stop, resolution):
    s_0 = 0
    s_1 = t_stop
    y0 = np.array([x_in, y_in])
    t_span = np.linspace(s_0, s_1, num=resolution)
    sol = solve_ivp(vector_field, [s_0, s_1], y0, method='Radau', t_eval=t_span)    
    return  sol.t, sol.y

def plot_dynamics_and_multi_traj1(vector_field, IVPs, x_left, x_right, x_res, y_down, y_up, y_res, density, normalized):
    '''
    vector_field = the function defining the vector field V to be integrated: 
                   input: x and y (arrays of) coordinates
                   output: a tuple of (arrays of) V_x and V_y calculated coordinates 
    IVP = array of arrays, each row contains: 
       [x_initial, 
        y_initial, 
        t_stop = time to stop, 
        number of discrete points in the time interval from [0, t_stop] (as float)]
    x_res = number of nodes on the x-axis
    y_res = number of nodes on the y-axis
    density = density of blue background trajectories to be drown
    normalized = set to False, unless you want to integrate the unit-normalized 
                 vector field, aligned with the original vector field.  
    '''
    if normalized:
      def vf(t, y):
        v = np.array( vector_field(y[0], y[1]) ) 
        return v / np.sqrt(v.dot(v))
      
    else:
      def vf(t, y): 
          return np.array(vector_field(y[0], y[1]))
      
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_aspect('equal') 

    x_min = x_left
    x_max = x_right
    y_min = y_down
    y_max = y_up

    for IVP in IVPs:
       x_in = IVP[0]
       y_in = IVP[1]
       t_stop = IVP[2]
       res_IVP = int(IVP[3])
       sol = solve_IVP(vf, x_in, y_in, t_stop, res_IVP)
       x_min = min(min(sol[1][0,:]), x_min)
       x_max = max(max(sol[1][0,:]), x_max)
       y_min = min(min(sol[1][1,:]), y_min)
       y_max = max(max(sol[1][1,:]), y_max)
       ax.plot(sol[1][0,:], sol[1][1,:], 'r')
       ax.set_aspect('equal')  

    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x_min, x_max, x_res), 
                       np.linspace(y_min, y_max, y_res))
    
    Vx, Vy = vector_field(x, y)

    if type(Vx) != object:
        Vx = Vx * np.ones(x.shape, dtype=float)
    if type(Vy) != object:
        Vy = Vy * np.ones(x.shape, dtype=float) 

    ax.streamplot(x, y, Vx, Vy, density=density)

    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

    return None
```

and applied it to your vector field

$$\vec{\text{VF}}(x, y) \, =\, y \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, +\,\big( -x^3- y  +  m\, y \, \big)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

```
# equations defining the vector field:
def VF(x, y):
  return (y,  -x**3 - y - m*x)
```

I set up a list of starting points selected horizontally over and under the x-horizontal axis (initial value parameters IVPs):

```
# bifurcation parameter
m = 1/2

# how many equally spaced nodes to select along the x-axis       
x_res = 100
# how many equally spaced nodes to select along the y-axis  
y_res = x_res

# the right endpoint of the plot on the x-axis  
x_size=0.5
# the top endpoint of the plot on the y-axis 
y_size=0.3
# for how much time to integrate the trajectories
stop_time = 12
# number of points along each trajectory to be used for integrating the equations
sample_points_on_trajectory = 500

# setting up the initial values:
# choose an array of initial points for a finite number of solution trajectories:
# set up the x-coordinates of the initial points:
IVPs =np.arange(-x_size, x_size, 2*x_size/10)
IVPs = np.concatenate((IVPs, - IVPs), axis=0)
 
# set up the initial value parameters:
# row1 = x-coordinates of initial points
# row2 = y-coordinates of initial points (left empty for now)
# row3 = 
IVPs = np.array([IVPs, 
                 np.empty(len(IVPs), dtype=float), 
                 stop_time * np.ones(len(IVPs), dtype=float),
                 sample_points_on_trajectory * np.ones(len(IVPs), dtype=float)])

# initializing row2 = y-coordinates of initial points:
# below the x-axis
IVPs[1 , 0:int(IVPs.shape[1]/2)] = - y_size 
# above the x-axis               
IVPs[1, int(IVPs.shape[1]/2): IVPs.shape[1]] = y_size

# transpose the initial value parameters:
IVPs = IVPs.T
```

and plotted the following two phase portraits:
$$m = \frac{1}{4}$$

```
# bifurcation parameter
m = 1/4

# plot the phase portrait:
plot_dynamics_and_multi_traj1(VF, IVPs,-x_size, x_size, x_res,
                                       -y_size, y_size, y_res, 
                                        density=0.7, normalized=False)
```

[image]

and $$m = -\,\frac{1}{8}$$

```
# bifurcation parameter
m=-1/8.

# plot the phase portrait:
plot_dynamics_and_multi_traj1(VF, IVPs,-x_size, x_size, x_res,
                                       -y_size, y_size, y_res, 
                                        density=0.5, normalized=False)
```

[image]

As you can see, when the bifurcation parameter $m$ goes from positive to negative values, the stable equilibrium point changes from being asymptotically stable focus to three equilibria, one saddle point in the middle and two symmetric stable nodes.